# Are backbone models and options passed by reference or by value to views

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, pass-by-reference

I was mostly wondering whether options (any models after the first) were passed by reference.

First model to pass:

```
App.testModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        passBy: "value"
    }
});
```

Second model to pass as in as options:

```
App.testModelOptions = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        passBy: "value"
    }
});
```

View that sets passedBy of the two models to "reference"

```
App.TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model1 = this.model;
        this.model2 = this.options.model2;

        this.model1.set({passBy: "reference"});
        this.model2.set({passBy: "reference"});
    }
});
```

Main:

```
// Router
App.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "":"test"
    }

    test:function() {
        this.testModel = new App.testModel();
        this.testModel2 = new App.testModelOptions();
        this.testView = new App.TestView({model: this.testModel, model2: this.testModel2});
        console.log(this.testModel.get("passBy"));
        console.log(this.testModel2.get("passBy"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you create an instance of a model, pass it to 20 views, and call `set({passBy: "reference"})` in one of those views - the property will be updated in the model for all views, as all those 20 views have a reference to the same model in memory. The same is true for any object which is passed to a view.